# How do I monitor and/or control the temperature of the SoC?

Tags: temperature, monitoring

Is there a way to programmatically monitor the temperature of the BCM2835 SoC?

If so, would it do any good? i.e. would temporarily suspending CPU-intensive processes have any chance to reduce the temperature?

I know that one answer is that it should not matter because air cooling is sufficient. However, this is for a situation where air flow in the enclosure is very limited (and the SoC and ethernet controllers are not necessarily the primary heat sources.)

Comment: Do you know how hot it is getting? (Hot to the touch?) Could you add a small heatsink? Or couple the chip to the enclosure with an external heatsink?

Comment: @Alex, probably, but this question is specifically about monitoring.

Comment: Can you tell me why this is important? Your Pi should never get hot enough to damage itself, even with low airflow.

Comment: @Jivings, I just fixed a typo in the question (which might address your comment.)  There may be other sources of heat, all in a confined space.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The [ability to monitor the temperature of the GPU](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/a274780149c0c441d57576411545289170da7d39) has been added to the firmware.

```
/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp
temp=48.7'C
```

Comment: works! very cool

Answer (score 26):

You can also type:

```
cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
```

Output will then be in milligrades!

Comment: Which, I believe, means `celsius = milligrades / 1000`, e.g. 40084 milligrades = 40.084 C.

Comment: That is correct berto!

Comment: Centigrade: `cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp | awk '{ print ($1 / 1000) "°C" }'`

Answer (score 10):

In addition to gnibbler's answer:

```
/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp| egrep "[0-9.]{4,}" -o
49.8
```

Answer (score 4):

<s>Unfortunately, the BCM2835 does not have a temperature sensor.</s>

<s>The documentation is rather limited (purposefully by Broadcom), however there is no mention of a sensor in [the data-sheet](http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf).</s>

It would be possible to attach your own sensor via the GPIO that monitors the surrounding air temperature or surface temperature of the chip.

However, unless the device will be operating inside your oven, I feel temperature shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some handy sensors that have a logic level to indicate if the temperature is above the setpoint https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1206/590. You just need one GPIO to detect if it is getting too hot.

Answer (score -1):

It is always good to watch the temp of the processor. You don't want it to go into nuclear overload. The CPU usage increase will increase the TEMP. I am new the Raspberry PI, but I am a tech. I do notice major increase in temp of the CPU with high processor usage. I am going to add a heat sink, and small fan to be controlled depending on heat rise.