# Variaty of sensors sitting on a single board for RPI

Tags: hardware, i2c, sensor

Is there a board that has a few different sensors sitting on top of it and able to talk to RPI via I2C/1-Wire?

Answer (score 1):

I've got a few answers on here using a variety of i2c chips

Temperature with [MCP9084](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1216/590)
Analog to digital with [ADS1115](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1326/590)
IO expander using [MCP23017](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1770/590)

I've also successfully connected a realtime clock module (search ebay for "DS1307 AT24C32"))