# How to configure the smarthost on Raspbian/xbian?

Tags: raspbian, xbian

I'm setting up [watchdog](http://pi.gadgetoid.co.uk/post/001-who-watches-the-watcher) to monitor my [RPi temperature](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/357/how-do-i-monitor-and-or-control-the-temperature-of-the-soc). I would like to have [e-mail messages](http://linux.die.net/man/5/watchdog.conf) sent out using [alias forwarding](https://serverfault.com/questions/207039/how-do-i-forward-roots-email-to-an-external-email-address). But how do I configure the smarthost on Raspbian/xbian?

Comment: Is it different to doing it on any other distro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer. I'm not sure about Raspbian but xbian version 1.0a4 doesn't have the mail utility installed. I first installed the mail utility as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install mailutils
```

Then I ran this command:

```
dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
```

I selected "mail sent by smarthost; no local mail" and configured the SMTP server of my ISP.