# Get PI's temperature using C

Tags: c, temperature

I know you can get the temperature using the tool **vcgencmd** but I was wondering if there is any API I can use in C to get the temperature programatically without reading the stdout of vcgencmd ?

Comment: You might find this useful: http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/sysfs-rules.txt

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can read the file `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp`, as specified in [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1951/2972). There it's about measuring from the command line, and the file is read with `cat`. But you should be able to just open the file in C. The temperature is returned in milli-degrees Centigrade and as ASCII numbers.
Perhaps like this, not tested :)

```
FILE *temperatureFile;
double T;
temperatureFile = fopen ("/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp", "r");
if (temperatureFile == NULL)
  ; //print some message
fscanf (temperatureFile, "%lf", &T);
T /= 1000;
printf ("The temperature is %6.3f C.\n", T);
fclose (temperatureFile);
```

Comment: Experience has lead me to believe the high level stream interface is not reliable on proc/sys files, and you should use `open()` and `read()` instead -- but YMMV.  There's also a "libsysfs", but it's been abandoned and the kernel devs have explicitly told people to stay away from it.

Comment: @goldilocks Interesting! I did not know this, thought it just behaves like any file. You may very well be  right.

Comment: According to the ["*official*" documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/overclocking.md), `vcgencmd measure_temp` and the value in `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp` are different temperatures. The documentation is rather vague on this (as it is on many hardware-related items), but it suggests that `vcgencmd` provides the `GPU` temp, and `/sys.../temp` is the `CPU` temp. In any event, the values are typically close.

Answer (score 2):

As @Frepa said, there is kernel thermal driver for RaspberryPi now so the easiest way is to use it. As far as I know, that's not the way `vgencmd` works however. It was able to read the temperature even before thermal kernel driver existed. It is using special communication mechanism available on RaspberryPi called `mailbox` in order to communicate with VideoCore OS running on GPU. It is partly documented [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/wiki/Mailboxes).

Comment: The [Baking Pi course](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/freshers/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/screen01.html) has some more mailbox material, however there it is used only for graphics.