# Does dust accumulation on raspberry pi causes heating problem

Tags: performance

My raspberry pi is placed where a lot of dust accumulates on the surface.I recently checked and there was a layer of dust settled on it.

I cleaned up the device and restarted it.

To my surprise, Its working a bit faster than before.

I want to know if dust reduces heat dissipation considerably to warrant cleaning it regularly.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from heat issues, dust can also cause other problems. Dust can be conductive, and could cause a short between chip pins. Dust can also capture moisture, which promotes corrosion.

When you say a lot of dust accumulates, or there was a layer of dust on it, that really does not quantify it much, but if it's enough that you are worried, you should look into placing your Pi in a case. Even one as simple as a small cardboard box would protect it from dust.

Answer (score 0):

From [the website](http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs)

> The Raspberry Pi is built from commercial chips which are qualified to different temperature ranges; the LAN9512 is specified by the manufacturers being qualified from 0°C to 70°C, while the AP is qualified from -40°C to 85°C. You may well find that the board will work outside those temperatures, but we’re not qualifying the board itself to these extremes.

The Raspberry Pi *does not have any issues with heating.* Ok... that is a bit of an exaggeration, but a little bit of dust should not affect it, or warrant cleaning it regularly. Unless you see temperature in excess of 60 C, you should not worry about heat-related performance issues.

If you are still concerned, you could create a program to monitor the heat. Please see [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/6978/6609) for more information.