# How do I monitor the temperature ever 3 seconds without entering new commands?

Tags: raspbian, temperature, monitoring

I just bought a heat sink kit for my pi and I'm using Raspbian and would like to monitor the temperature continuously every 3 seconds via SSH while I perform tasks on the pi so that I don't have to keep manually entering in a command to display the current temperature, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command for viewing the current temperature is found in this post: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1847/22221

To automate this such that you can view the temperature every 3 seconds without entering new commands can be accomplished by writing a simple shell script that has an infinite loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Press [ctrl+c] to end monitoring"
echo ""

while true
do
  vcgencmd measure_temp
  sleep 3s
done
```

Place that text in a file called `monitor-temp` and place it in `~/bin/` (if `!/bin/` doesn't already exist, then just create it with `mkdir ~/bin`). Make `monitor-temp` executable: `chmod 755 ~/bin/monitor-temp`. End your terminal (or ssh) session and start a new one. Now you can run `monitor-temp` from any location in the file system via ssh or directly on the machine and you'll see something like the following:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ monitor-temp
Press [ctrl+c] to end monitoring

temp=48.7'C
temp=48.7'C
temp=49.2'C
temp=49.2'C
temp=48.7'C
```

Answer (score 9):

I think using `watch` command is much easier, for example:

```
watch {your command}
```

In your case, it will be:

```
watch vcgencmd measure_temp
```

That will refresh by 2 seconds, if you want to define the interval by yourself (5 second maybe), you can type:

```
watch -n 5 <your command>
```

In your case, it will be:

```
watch -n 5 vcgencmd measure_temp
```

You can cancel that with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: much more elegant and simple, thanks for the response

Comment: the use of *watch* is new to me. very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a few more bells as whistles, see the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for count in $(seq 1 100); do
    echo -n "$(vcgencmd measure_temp | echo "$(sed -E 's/.*([0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]).*/\1/g')" | echo "$(xargs)*1.8" | bc | echo "$(xargs)+32" | bc | echo "$(xargs)'F / $(vcgencmd measure_temp | sed -E 's/.*([0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]).*/\1/g')'C")\r"
    sleep 3s
done
```

The main benefit of this script is that the line carriage is removed so that you don't overflow your terminal window with new lines. Additionally, the temperature in F and C is displayed.

Sample output:

```
94.1'F / 35.0'C
```

This will terminate after 100 checks but can easily be modified to run indefinitely if preferred.

I created the following alias for this script in my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias temp="sh temp_script.sh"
```

*NOTE: The removed carriages returns only works when executing via "sh" command (i.e. executing script via `./temp_script.sh` does not respect the `\r` special character for some reason). Also, there is some redundancy in the echo command, but I made the tradeoff of having it be a one liner. Lastly, Fahrenheit conversion is a bit wonky and doesn't match up perfectly, although the input formula should be correct.*